# Dynamic category select

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

So I have a dropdown where user selects a category. But I want to make it more user firendly so that it automaticaly selects the `category id` and post it in that category.

My cshtml:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.category.Id, "category", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", required = "" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.category, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

My controler:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(db.Categorys, "Id", "Title", db.Categorys);
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Title,CategoryId,Content")] Thread thread)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        thread.ApplicationUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        db.Threads.Add(thread);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Post", new { @id = thread.Id });
    }
    ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(db.Categorys, "Id", "Title", thread.Id);
    return View(thread);
}
```

What should I do to make it dynamic, so that the user don't have to select a `category id`, but the `select` element does it by itself.

Comment: What do you mean _but the select element does it by itself_? Are you wanting that if the value of your model property `CategoryId` is say `5` and then the option with a value of `5` will be selected when you first display the view?

Answer (score 0):

Use `DropDownListFor` and specify appropriate model property to store your valun in and it will do it for you.

`@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CatId, Model.List, null)` where `CatId` is a property in your model, `List` is a list of items to show as values in `select` element. Instead of `null` in the third parameter you can specify additional html attributes for this element (e.g. `id`, `class`)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, could you try take my cshtml and edit it? :)

Comment: That's not what i'm looking for :) I'm looking for a way where the user dosen't have to selecet a category but it automaticly chose after wich, category my user did go in. Example, if you go to hearthstone cateogry, and create a thread, it automaticly select to post it inside of hearthstone with id 3

Comment: In this case I think you need some JavaScript only

Comment: I don't i know i can create it without :)